# How to translate facet filter view search assertions/statements into Russian?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, search

How to translate facet filter view search assertions/statements into Russian? See the attached image. Want to write these statements in pure Russian to make friendly for the local shop customers. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just import your own translations, creating a simple *.po file.
The structure of that file you can get from https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html (or just google the example).
Import your own translations available by uri [yoursite]/admin/config/regional/translate/import

Comment: What modules are responsible for these translation strings?

Comment: This functionality provided by core (I'm usind D7).

Check that "Locale" module is enabled.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multilingual/translating-site-interfaces/install-a-language

Look at "Update strings (manual method)"

Remember, that you can always import just one string, not the whole lang.